# PowerShell and $null as method parameter

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

Is PowerShell's `$null` equivalent to .NET's `null`? I have a scenario, wherein I have to invoke a .NET method from PowerShell and pass `null` as method parameter. As of now, I am getting some assembly loading related error on method invocation. I am wondering if `$null` is the culprit. Also, please share if you know what is the correct way of invoking .NET method with `null` parameter from PowerShell.

Method signature:

```
void SetUp(IKernel kernel, Action<IBindingInSyntax<object>> obj)
```

Thanks

Comment: The method parameter is `nullable` ? Could you post  the method's sign?

Comment: Yes. It's a reference type variable.

Comment: if you are in powershell version 2.0 and the param is string type try to declare the variable as `[System.Management.Automation.Language.NullString]::Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell converts it's $null to .NET's null just fine in function calls.

Proof by example.

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
public static class Foo
{
    public static bool IsNull(object o)
    {
        return o == null;
    }
}
"@ -Language CSharp

[Foo]::IsNull($null)

[Foo]::IsNull("string")
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

**$null** wraps a null reference to an **object**, and no wonder it just works, even though they are two different things.

Comment: This does not work if the type is something else other than `object`. In my case, it was a `SecureString`.

Comment: > Object Class -- Supports all classes in the .NET class hierarchy and provides low-level services to derived classes. This is the ultimate base class of all .NET classes; it is the root of the type hierarchy.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-5.0
@julealgon, I doubt `SecureString` is not an Object. Maybe you should ask a question and offer an example where this does not work.

Comment: `SecureString` is an object for sure, and I'm pretty sure it does not work there. I don't think asking another question is the way to go since it would be the same question as this one. I think this is the correct place to bring it up. Just replace `object` parameter on your method with `SecureString` (or anything other than `object` that is a reference type) and you should see the issue as well.