# How do I pass a parameter that should be $null in powershell via C#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server-2010

Exchange management requires you to pass $null as a parameter to remove forwarding from a mailbox:

Set-Mailbox  -ForwardingAddress $null -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $false

This (IMHO) translates to:

```
command = new PSCommand().AddCommand("Set-Mailbox");
          command.AddParameter("Identity",task.TargetUser);
          command.AddParameter("FowardingAddress", null);
          command.AddParameter("DeliverToMailboxAndForward", false);
ps.Commands=command;
var results = ps.Invoke();
```

Unfortunately, the Invoke chokes on the "ForwardingAddress" setting: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FowardingAddress'.

How can I pass a parameter that ends up as $null?

Comment: Have you tried just leaving it out?

Comment: @SteveMitcham - doesn't modify the forwarding if I don't set SOMETHING for ForwardingAddress

Comment: Sorry, misread the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `null` should work fine. As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739802/powershell-and-null-as-method-parameter) shows, C#'s nulls are mapped to $null.

Assuming the code you're showing is copy-pasted directly from your solution, I'm guessing the problem is that you're passing a value to the parameter "FowardingAddress", rather than "ForwardingAddress" (note the missing 'r'). A simple typo, not a type mismatch. :)

Comment: Urgh.  Freeform parameter values are the death of me.  Fixed! Thanks.

Comment: Good eye.  I had to look at those two for about 30 seconds before I saw where the missing 'r' was supposed to be.  Dang brain auto-correct.  :-)

Answer (score 8):

If that parameter is of type string then you should be able to pass this value:

```
System.Management.Automation.Language.NullString.Value
```

or include

```
using System.Management.Automation.Language;
```

and then later

```
command.AddParameter("ForwardingAddress",NullString.Value);
```

Another option is to use `$null` via the `AddScript` method:

```
var script = String.Format("Set-Mailbox -Identity {0} -ForwardingAddress $null -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $false", task.TargetUser);
new PSCommand().AddScript(script);
```

Comment: How would I put that in my c# code?  I'm a bit perplexed.

Comment: System.Management.Automation.Language.NullString.Value

Comment: Sadly, it looked quite promising, but still comes back with the same error :(

Comment: Which turns out to be fat-finger syndrome on my part.